# Sitefinity Backend not working - 404 Page not found

Tags: sitefinity

I am using Sitefinity CMS for my project. I am developing project on localhost. Uptill now all were going well. but, before 2 days when I try to open Sitefinity backend by entering http://localhost:60879/sitefinity, I am getting 404 Page not found error and redirect me to http://localhost:60879/404?aspxerrorpath=/Sitefinity/Authenticate/SWT

moreover, when I host this website on IIS with same physical path, it starts working. What I have tried so far

- clear browsing history and restart
- restart visual studio and run the code
- check App_Data/Error.log

> Error.log

Timestamp: 1/18/2017 7:04:00 AM

Message: HandlingInstanceID: 350f050d-ae62-4d9e-b491-d43e0cfa2c5f

### An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred and was caught.

01/18/2017 12:34:00
Type : System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Stack empty.
Source : System
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void ThrowInvalidOperationException(System.ExceptionResource)
HResult : -2146233079
Stack Trace :    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingRenderTraceListener.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject)
   at System.Web.UI.RenderTraceListener.RenderTraceListenerList.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Additional Info:

MachineName : BRVM120
TimeStamp : 1/18/2017 7:04:00 AM
FullName : Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities, Version=8.2.5900.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563
AppDomainName : /LM/W3SVC/17/ROOT-1-131291960014867668
ThreadIdentity : 
WindowsIdentity : BRSOBO\hardik.gondalia
Requested URL : http://localhost:60879/Sitefinity/Authenticate/SWT?realm=http://localhost:60879/&redirect_uri=/sitefinity&deflate=true

Category: ErrorLog

Priority: 0

EventId: 90000

Severity: Error

Title:Enterprise Library Exception Handling

Machine: BRVM120

App Domain: /LM/W3SVC/17/ROOT-1-131291960014867668

ProcessId: 10520

Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe

Thread Name:

Win32 ThreadId:12936

Extended Properties:

I don't know how to make it work as it is the sitefinity in-box functionality.

Comment: Did you enable SSL on your site?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post: http://www.sitefinitytipsandtricks.net/2016/08/18/fix-for-sitefinity-backend-issue-iis-detailed-error-404-0-not-found/

It suggests to follow all steps from the Sitefinity Documentation portal for configuring IIS to host your site:
http://docs.sitefinity.com/configure-the-iis-to-host-sitefinity-projects#windows-server-2012-r2-and-windows-8-1-with-iis-8-5

and if that does not help to check this article as well:

http://therobgregory.com/sitefinity-backend-issue-iis-detailed-error-404-0-not-found/